# jax-rs in weblogic high memory

Tags: jax-rs, weblogic

We are currently using JAX-RS 2.0 jersey on WebLogic for hosting restful web services . We are observing very high heap memory utilization in the benchmarks that keep increasing with time. Even after benchmark is over the heap memory allocated does not get released even after I hit perform GC on jconsole. When I analyze the heap dump with MAT I see ~99% of the heap is consumed by oracle.j2ee.ws.server.jaxrs.dms.monitoring.internal.DmsApplication. I un-targetted DMS from the managed server but still the same behavior.

A Little bit of analysis of dominator tree in heap dump shows that every request is being tracked by the listener. The weblogic.jaxrs.monitoring.JaxRsRequestEventListener is mapped to oracle.j2ee.ws.server.jaxrs.dms.monitoring.DmsApplicationEventListener.

Am I understanding this correctly? Does JAX-RS jersey maps to DMS request event listener internally. How this can be configured correctly so we don't face this memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at your diagnostic module in weblogic. Look at watches & notifications